# How to get a local file using axios?

Tags: react-native, axios

I am trying to get a local file:

Resultado.js:

```
componentWillMount(){
  axios.get('../config/db.json')
  .then(function(response){
    alert('ok');
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    alert('error');
  });
}
```

But, I am receiving an error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

[image]

The file exists on the path

My file db.json:

```
[{"id":"87","codigo":"00504.050.000.00.00","nomeCadastro":"GOIVO DOBRADO"},{"id":"86","codigo":"02023.050.000.10.02","nomeCadastro":"GERB ONEDIN"},{"id":"85","codigo":"00212.070.999.00.00","nomeCadastro":"CRIS SANT REAN"},{"id":"84","codigo":"01297.019.000.00.00","nomeCadastro":"ANTH VARIADO"}]
```

Comment: `axios` is used for HTTP method. In your case, simply import your data and use it `import data from '../config/db.json'`

Comment: The above comment is correct. You could also `cd` into the config directory and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` - Then call `http://localhost:8000/db.json`.

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy how to use the data. can you write an example?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo you can `console.log` it in arbitrary function to see :))

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy I edit the question and add my json file

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy I am beginner on ReactNative. If you tell me an example will very usefull

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just import data from `json` file and use it

```
    import data from '../config/db.json';

    render(){
     if(data){
      // do whatever you want with data here, 
     }
     ....
    }
```

Comment: What if it's static HTML, importing it does not work