# Trying to consume a .json but Vue-CLI doesn't find the file

Tags: api, vue.js, vue-cli

I had a `SQL database` that I've fetched with `json_encode`. I've copied the result in a `.json` to try to consume it with `Vue-cli`. So, I've put the file in `assets`, then `components`, but in `console`, I always have this message :

```
GET http://localhost:8080/assets/fetch.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Also, here is the code I've put in App.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { dm: [], error: [] };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$axios
      .get("views/fetch.json")
      .then(response => {
        this.dm = response.data;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.error.push(e);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

and to consume it :

```
  <tr v-for="(dm, index) in dm" :key="index">
    <td>{{ dm.id_dm }}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a local file using axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235628/how-to-get-a-local-file-using-axios)

Comment: Not really, I believe axios is not installed on my Vue-CLI. I'm looking for a way to check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what project structure you have but have you tried importing the file directly with the `import` statement instead of using `axios` like so:

```
<script>
 import data from "@/views/fetch.json"
</script>
```

You can then assign the `data` in `mounted()` to some other variable that you could loop through, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've done this : 

import data from "@/views/fetch.json";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: []
    }
  },

But now it shows that there's a problem with : 

mounted() axios.get("@/views/fetch.json").then(response => console.log(response))

the problem is on axios. I removed everything and then I reinstalled everything including axios but still the same problem. I've been checking on google how to check if axios is properly installed but I didnt find anything. I'm getting crazy. Sorry for my ignorance, I recently started using vuejs.

Comment: Again, in this case, I do not think that you need to use `axios` necessarily.

After you imported the `data` as I mentioned before, initiate a variable like so: 

`data() {
    return { myLocalData: null };
  },`

After that in `mounted()` assign the `data` to `myLocalData` like so:

`this.myLocalData = data`

Try `console.log(this.myLocalData)` afterward to see if the data has been assigned.
If it was then you can start using `myLocalData`. Use it to loop through in your HTML template like you did before with `v-for`.

I hope that clarifies. Good luck!